# Big Oh and Omega notation complexity proof

Tags: complexity-theory, proof

1. Prove that n<sup>3</sup> is not in O(n<sup>2</sup>)
2. Prove that n<sup>3</sup> is not in OMEGA(n<sup>4</sup>)

Comment: it's a question from previous test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Suppose that n³ is in O(n²), then there exists some pair of positive constants `c` and `n₀` such that `n³ ≤ cn²` for all `n ≥ n₀`, but for any constant `c` this is trivially false when `n > c`, thus we have a contradiction.
2. Suppose that n³ is in Ω(n⁴), then there exists some pair of positive constants `c` and `n₀` such that `n³ ≥ cn⁴` for all `n ≥ n₀`, but for any constant `c`, this is trivially false when `n > max(1,1/c)`, thus we have a contradiction.